# WHMCS - add Product custom fields to invoice

Tags: php, mysql, customization, invoice, whmcs

I added 2 Product custom fields:
Contract # & Order date.

But when i create the PDF-Invoice, by default they shows in product description - under 1st line.

*example:*

- Product name
- Contract #
- Order Date

So i want somehow to customize it, lets say to show the Contract # at another place (top right corner, or anywhere around) together with Order date.

So with some code to get (call em) and put in another place on the invoicepdf.tpl file! But there isn't anything about Product custom fields at WHMCS Documentation.